# Export Specific Page of a PDF to TIFF

Tags: pdf, export, tiff, ghostscript

I have a lot of PDFs that I need to convert a single page from to a TIFF. Acrobat would let me batch this for ALL pages but that would take too much space.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use [Ghostscript](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/). It gives you a lot of controls over various aspects of your TIFF output. Here are a few commandline examples:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o mytiffpage.tif ^
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
  -dFirstPage=13 ^
  -dLastPage=15 ^
   input.pdf
```

This will create a multipage TIFF G4 (compressed fax format, which is grayscale) from pages 13-15 of your *input.pdf*, with the default resolution, which is 204dpi (width) by 196dpi (height).

Let's say you want each of the pages as an individual TIFF file, and you want a uniform resolution of 600dpi. Then specify the command like this:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o mytiffpage_%03d.tif ^
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
  -dFirstPage=13 ^
  -dLastPage=15 ^
  -r600x600 ^
   input.pdf
```

Your output pages will be named `mytiffpage_001.tif` ... `mytiffpage_003.tif`. Let's say you want CMYK color TIFFs with 8 bit depth per channel, compressed, just the single page 14 from the input.pdf, at a resolution of 300 dpi:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -o mytiffpage_p14.tif ^
  -sDEVICE=tiff32nc ^
  -dFirstPage=14 ^
  -dLastPage=14 ^
  -sCompression=lzw ^
  -r300 ^
   input.pdf
```

For more options look at the Ghostscript [usage](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.02/doc/Use.htm) and [device](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.02/doc/Devices.htm) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU/Linux try installing **pdfjam**, then:

> pdfjoin file.pdf 1

The number at the end of the previous command supposes you want to convert page number 1 of *file.pdf*, change it at your will. This will output a file called *file-joined.pdf* containing only page number 1. After that execute:

> convert file-joined.pdf file-joined.tiff

**convert** has lots of options to style the final output of your tiff file. Check the [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for more info.

You'll need imagemagick to have the **convert** command. To install both packages in a debian-based distribution do as a root:

> apt-get install pdfjam imagemagick

enjoy!

Comment: Maybe helpful, but the question is most probably about Windows (the OP is using Acrobat).